# Blogger add alternate text with post title text

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

i want to automatically add alt text to each image populated with post title . Below i have piece of code that can do that but it use image name instead of post title. Can anyone help please?

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 //<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function(){
   var $img = $(this);
   var filename = $img.attr('src')
   $img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
   $img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
  });
 });
 //]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're getting the post title anywhere. Is there a class on the HTML for the post title that you can target in your loop, something like `var postTitle = $img.closest(".post-title").text();` ? Then, just change the `alt` to be equal to that on your last line of the loop.

Comment: class is .post-title

Answer (score 0):

$img represents the current image inside your loop.  $img.attr(attributeName, value) is a jquery function that sets the text for a specific attribute.  Below is an example if the post title is stored under an element with the class "post-title".

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);

    var postTitle = $('.post-title') // get all the elements with the class post-title
      .first() // get the first element
      .text(); // get the text in the element

    $img.attr('title', postTitle); // set text of title
    $img.attr('alt', postTitle); // set text of alt
});
```

Comment: i don't know how blogger is getting the post title

Comment: @Nonick, I meant how are ***you*** getting the post title, I see above you mentioned that there is a class on the post-title element, I changed my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: Here is what i found in blogger template, so maybe this gonna help "<b:includable id='posts' var='posts'>
  <ul class='posts hierarchy'>
    <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
      <li>
        <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
      </li>
    </b:loop>
  </ul>
</b:includable>"

Comment: though, i tried to place like this $(this).attr('alt', '<data:post.title/>'); and it returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list and insede title  tag text is replaced with "'<!--Can't find substitution for tag [post.title]-->'". also when i use <data:blog.title/> it works fine

Comment: Try using F12 tools to look at the actual DOM after your page renders, make sure the blogger framework isn't messing with your page during load.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chromium v65

Comment: I don't use Chromium, is there no dev tools? There is in Chrome. If not, I would get a different browser for debugging.

Comment: There are dev tools but i get no other errors except this one "<!--Can't find substitution for tag [post.title]-->"